# How to fix relation does not exist -error when using class meta in model?

Tags: python, django

I have this class in my models.py:

```
class Person(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(

        User,

        on_delete=models.CASCADE,

        primary_key=True,

    )

    birthday = models.DateField(null=True)

    gender = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    height = models.CharField(max_length=3)

    id = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=100)

    weight = models.CharField(max_length=3)


    class Meta:

        managed = False

        db_table = 'person'



    def __str__(self):

        return self.id
```

Everytime I run migrate -command I get this error: `psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "person" does not exist`. I've already dropped the db and destroyed the migration file but the error remains. How can I fix this and why this happens?

Comment: how did you destroy migration?

Comment: @SırrıKırımlıoğlu I deleted the migration file. I also dropped the whole database.